# Problem with selecting trained polygons from points in nested loop gee python

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

I am trying to translate a SNIC segmentation example performed in javascript to python (posted on Medium by Joao Otavio Nascimento Firigato
with the code in javascript: https://code.earthengine.google.com/eb2890d3ddf09633dfaa13e41bafd2fc

I am struggling to convert the following section of the code to python:

```
var train_polys = vectors.map(function(feat){
  feat = ee.Feature(feat);
  var point = feat.geometry();

  var mappedPolys = train_points.map(function(poly){
    var cls = poly.get("Class");
    var intersects = poly.intersects(point, ee.ErrorMargin(1));
    var property = ee.String(ee.Algorithms.If(intersects, 'TRUE', 'FALSE'));
    return feat.set('belongsTo',  property).set('Class', cls);
  });
  return mappedPolys;
}).flatten().filter(ee.Filter.neq('belongsTo', 'FALSE'));
```

In this code, vectors is a feature collection of segments created with the SNIC algorithm and train_points is a feature collection of training data containing the class information. I have tried several version to replicate the code in python gee api without success. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The python version of this code will have `def` in defining the functions and adding `lambda` to the map functions. Lastly you can get the train_polys by mapping over the functions and doing flattening and filtering just as before.

```
    # Function for points
    def point_function(feat):
        feat = ee.Feature(feat)
        point = feat.geometry()

        # Function for the polygons
        def poly_function(poly):
            cls = poly.get("Class")
            intersects = poly.intersects(point, ee.ErrorMargin(1))
            property = ee.String(ee.Algorithms.If(intersects, 'TRUE', 'FALSE'))
            return feat.set('belongsTo', property).set('Class', cls)
    
        mapped_polys = train_points.map(lambda p: poly_function(p))
        return mapped_polys

     train_polys = ((vectors.map(lambda v: point_function(v)).flatten().filter(ee.Filter.neq('belongsTo', 'FALSE')))
```